# Unable to Convert DateTime value to UTC

Tags: c#, json, datetime, utc

I am trying to fetch data from database and convert datetime value to UTC using C#

I have tried this, which is not working.

```
foreach (GrJscMstr gjm in grJscMstrs)
                {
                    gjm.gr_sch_date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(gjm.gr_sch_date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
```

Then, I tried this, which is also not working:

```
foreach (GrJscMstr gjm in grJscMstrs)
                {
                    gjm.gr_sch_date = new DateTime(gjm.gr_sch_date.Year, gjm.gr_sch_date.Month, gjm.gr_sch_date.Day, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
```

Then I modified my code to this which is working fine.

```
foreach (GrJscMstr gjm in grJscMstrs)
                {
                    gjm.gr_sch_date = new DateTime(gjm.gr_sch_date.Year, gjm.gr_sch_date.Month, gjm.gr_sch_date.Day, 0, 0, **1**, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
```

I need to know why. It does not make any sense to me. `DateTime.SpecifyKind(gjm.gr_sch_date, DateTimeKind.Utc);` should be working fine.

Comment: What type is gr_sch_date?

Comment: Is `gjm.gr_sch_date` a `DateTime` value in local timezone? If it so, try using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(gjm.gr_sch_date.Date, DateTimeKind.Local))`. If it is unspecified date, use `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` instead. If you just reconfigure timezone to UTC, AFAIK, `DateTime.SpecifyKind(gjm.gr_sch_date, DateTimeKind.Utc)` converts to UTC without using timezone difference.

Comment: Those are terribly named variable and classes.

Comment: @CodingYoshi DateTime

Comment: @Kinetic I know! But, legacy code. Nothing to do here. :-(

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks. But this field is unspecified. I need to convert this to UTC in server. In client, I am converting back to UTC.

Interesting thing is I have another class and in that class, it's working fine!

Comment: @Lonely, please read [MCVE] guidance - SO *is not* [CodeReview.SE] - you are expected to provide nicely formatted *example* demonstrating the problem preferably following default style guidelines for language you are using. There is no value for community  in showing that you dislike style of code you have locally.

Comment: @LonelyPlaneteer Can you describe *how* it isn't working? Is it throwing errors? Is it failing to return the correct value? What *specifically* is not working about it.

Comment: @EBrown It's not throwing errors. But, it's not converting the datetime to UTC either. It's showing me unspecified after executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Lonely Planeteer does not specify what "not working" means. The following example demonstrates how the kind of a DateTime can be changed, loosely speaking, by using the syntax desired by the Lonely Planeteer. Perhaps this full working example will allow Lonely Planeteer to find the problem.

```
using System;

namespace StOv3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime unspecifiedTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            DateTime localTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
            DateTime utcTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Console.WriteLine("A DateTime, unspecified whether UTC or local {0}, Kind {1}", unspecifiedTime, unspecifiedTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A local DateTime {0}, Kind {1}", localTime, localTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A UTC DateTime {0}, Kind {1}", utcTime, utcTime.Kind);
            // Attempt to redefine variables with same values;

            unspecifiedTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            localTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
            utcTime = new DateTime(2016, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Console.WriteLine("A DateTime, unspecified whether UTC or local {0}, Kind {1}", unspecifiedTime, unspecifiedTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A local DateTime {0}, Kind {1}", localTime, localTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A UTC DateTime {0}, Kind {1}", utcTime, utcTime.Kind);

            // Attempt to change kind of variable

            unspecifiedTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(unspecifiedTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            localTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(localTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
            utcTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(utcTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Console.WriteLine("A DateTime, originally unspecified whether UTC or local {0}, Kind {1}",
                unspecifiedTime, unspecifiedTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A DateTime, originally local {0}, Kind {1}", localTime, localTime.Kind);
            Console.WriteLine("A DateTime, originally UTC {0}, Kind {1}", utcTime, utcTime.Kind);

        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
A DateTime, unspecified whether UTC or local 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Unspecified
A local DateTime 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Local
A UTC DateTime 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Utc
A DateTime, unspecified whether UTC or local 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Unspecified
A local DateTime 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Local
A UTC DateTime 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Utc
A DateTime, originally unspecified whether UTC or local 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Utc
A DateTime, originally local 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Unspecified
A DateTime, originally UTC 12/8/2016 00:00:00, Kind Utc
```